# Probit model with error term

Tags: error, probit

I'm writing a probit model but I don't know if the error term is written correctly.

I wrote my model like this:

$$\Pr(Y_i=1|X_i)=Φ(x'_i\beta) + ν_i$$

where $v_i$ is the error term. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hello Nell and welcome to Cross Validated!

This is not exactly correct.

The model is given by the assumption,

$$\Pr[Y=1|X]=\Phi(X^T\beta)$$

where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.

So in this equation, we do not have an error term because we assume the probabilities are specified like this.

The way this is typically motivated is with a latent variable model,

$$Y^*=X^T\beta + \epsilon$$

where $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$ is the error term. $Y^*$ is viewed as some auxiliary random variable that we do not observe but for which the binary $Y$ indicates some cutoff. Usually that cutoff will be $0$. So,

$$\Pr[Y=1|X]=\Pr[Y^*>0]=\Pr[X^T\beta+\epsilon>0]=\Pr[\epsilon < X^T\beta]$$

Then using the fact that $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$ we have,

$$=\Phi(X^T\beta)$$

From this point, we can just use maximum likelihood to estimate this model because for any single observation we essentially consider the estimate of the probability a Bernoulli-p parameter and use the $Y_i$ to tell us if we are estimating $\Pr[Y=1|X]$ or $\Pr[Y=0|X]$.

I encourage you to check out the Wikipedia page on the [Probit model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20a%20probit%20model,%2C%20coming%20from%20probability%20%2B%20unit.) so you can read through some more details.